# Ember binding not working

Tags: ember.js

I've been trying to make bindings work in Ember with a really simple example but they don't work properly. It shouldn't be a matter of synchronization since I'm calling Ember.run.sync(). The code that I'm using is the following:

```
var MyApp = Ember.Application.create();
MyApp.initialize();

MyApp.president = Ember.Object.create({
        name: "Barack Obama"
});

MyApp.country = Ember.Object.create({
      // Ending a property with 'Binding' tells Ember to
      //   // create a binding to the presidentName property.
      presidentNameBinding: 'MyApp.president.name'
});

// Later, after Ember has resolved bindings...
Em.run.sync();
console.log(MyApp.country.get('presidentName'));​
```

And I've also created a fiddle here.

http://jsfiddle.net/XKsNr/

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at the Emberist blog, especially the article on naming conventions http://goo.gl/hTt1I

Comment: Is this a problem with variable scope, such as window.MyApp, rather than about binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare MyApp without "var", the first line should be:

```
MyApp = Ember.Application.create();
```

See more details here: http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.Application&src=false

Comment: yes, MyApp should be a variable at the window level of the website.  Also, I have been starting to always call my app App instead of MyApp or other names, which helps me a lot, when porting common code from one project to another.